# Does InnoDB related with IN_USE?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a website with a database (MySQL).
My database is about 35 mb (not too big).
My tables' engines are InnoDB.
all my queries are select queries except tow of them (one UPDATE and the other INSERT).

The website is fast most of the time but sometimes (random times maybe each minute or each ten minutes or even each day,...) it slows down like the following:
if we have two users :
user1 is making an insert then update;
then (simultaneously) user2 asking for select query(http request for the home page).
the user2 should stop sometime (this is the problem) until the user1 finishes his query.

And you can imagine if there are two or three users making insert and update at the same time maybe the select query will still waiting for 3 or 4 minutes.
by monitoring the phpmyadmin on my linux server (hosting server) I found that when anybody make an INSERT or Update to specific table all other select queries will stop until this user finish his query.
Important note: all my select queries using this table to get some information from it.
NOW my tables are InnoDB so I do not think it is table lock problem .
but when I check the open tables to see which of them are locked (IN_USE):

```
show open tables
```

I found that the value of IN_USE is not 0 . when somebody make update it will show IN_USE as 1 or 2 or even 17 sometimes .

My question is Why the IN_USE variable sometimes shows not zero while all my tables are InnoDB ?
I mean InnoDB does not apply table locks so why IN_USE (which indicates tables in lock) shows a value sometimes?

Comment: Maybe your query is not optimized and accidently locks more rows than you want it to lock, thus it may look like a whole table lock? Just a guess, maybe you should provide the few queries you think are involved.

Comment: I want to say that my tables was MyISAM before but I changed the whole tables to InnoDB but I did not restart the sql server could that be related to the problem. I mean could the tables still in MyISAM .? But when I see them in myphpadmin it shows they are InnoDB?

Comment: MySQL flushes its table buffer to the disc, this is not a problem. Do you have proper index and (foreign)keys?

Comment: I have primary key and indexs but no foreign keys because i read in some articles that the constrains of the foreign keys are generating too much overhead on the database , and in INNODB it is not recommended!!!

Comment: if you don't want to use the features of innodb, why did you change to it? MyISAM is faster if you need its features rather than innodb features.

Comment: I use InnoDB to get rid of table locks but it seems i did not because i still have the same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43592/discussion-between-basel-and-danfromgermany)